# How to test my installation script on macOS?

Tags: bash

What is the best way to test an install script on macOS?

I have written an installation script so that others can easily install the program [qme-ng](https://github.com/mathyingzhou/qme-ng/) which I forked and am working on.

However testing the script is very hard. I can manually uninstall all the dependencies, [Boost](https://www.boost.org) and [gmp](https://gmplib.org), each time and see whether my script can properly reinstall them but it is very costly. Furthermore I'm worried about the possibility of dependency removal that isn't complete which can complicate the issue.

Comment: Get macOS running in a VM :-)

Comment: @nohillside Sure! Well, I thought about that before..does that cost any extra money?

Comment: @YingZhou No...

Comment: Depends on the VM software you use. VirtualBox is free, Parallels/VMware cost something

Comment: @nohillside Partially incorrect. The full version of Parallels costs but in the App Store there is “Parallels Lite” which is free. Parallels lite can run macOS and Linux free, just can’t run Windows free.

Comment: @jbis indeed, the restrictions are amazingly small http://kb.parallels.com/en/123796

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a macOS VM for testing. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (it's free), create a macOS virtual machine, and then create a [snapshot](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots) before testing your script. Once you've finished testing your script you can restore the VM to its previous, unmodified state using the snapshot feature. Hope this helps!

Comment: I can confirm that this method works beautifully with VirtualBox.  I am creating an installation script to automate the creation of a desktop environment for FreeBSD 11 and the snapshot feature works great for resetting back to an initial state.